# Build succeeded but a gradle error gets thrown

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I've setup my Cordova tools on Visual Studio 2015 update 3.

I am currently using Cordova version 7.1.0 and created a blank Cordova project, but when building this error gets print on the build output:

`Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "path\to\project\platforms\android\gradlew.bat cdvBuildDebug -b path\to\project\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"`

Regardless the error, the application seems to be working fine and it loads correctly on the Android emulator.

Any idea of what the problem could be?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Most likely an issue with Visual Studio. Do you have any plugins enabled like ReSharper? I remember that I had to turn off mine to get it to work properly without throwing errors.

Comment: No I don't, I only have the plugins that got installed on Cordova feature install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `error code 0` here means that there wasn't any error at all, so you can safely ignore that message.

You should worry only when you don't see error code 0, that's when you'll get errors but usually they have a detailed description included.